# How to validate an array of strings in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

in a User entity I have a field called "roles" which is an array.
I want to be able to validate it to allow only specific strings (role names) I tried this:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type;
    class User{
        #[Collection(['ROLE_USER' => new Type('string'), 'ROLE_ADMIN' => new Type('string')])]
        #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
        private $roles = [];
    }
```

But thats not working as expected. I get this when I validate:

```
roles[ROLE_USER]: This field is missing.
roles[ROLE_ADMIN]: This field is missing.
roles[0]: This field was not expected.
```

I set the user role like this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setRoles([$request->get('role')]);
```

I am not sure if I should use Collection constraint here. It should be allowed to save an array with only these values "ROLE_USER" and/or "ROLE_ADMIN". Any ideas?

Comment: Combine the [`All`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html) and [`Choice`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#basic-usage) constraints

Comment: @msg - thanks! this works. I created an answer to my question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @msg comment under my question, I combined the All and Choice constraints which is exactly what I need:

```
#[All([new Choice(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'])])]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
private $roles = [];
```